# Same databases but different explain results

Tags: mysql

I have 2 databases: localhost & remotehost. Localhost seems to function well and gets my results quickly (well under 1 second...thanks to help from this board). Using mysqldump, I dumped localhost to remotehost, including the table structure, indices, & data. I expected remotehost to be a virtual replica of localhost but when I run my queries on remotehost they take > 1 minute to execute. The explain statements are even different...there are a bunch of differences, including changing the 'type' to 'range' and also the index used, among others.

(some of this could probably be fixed by forcing it to use the PRIMARY index, but I'd rather get to the root of the problem and understand why remotehost behaves differently)

My Statement:

```
SELECT names.id, names.first, addr.last FROM names, addr WHERE names.first LIKE 'H%' AND addr.last IS NOT NULL AND names.id = addr.id GROUP BY names.id LIMIT 10
```

EXPLAIN statement from localhost:

```
id| select_type|table|type |possible_keys  |key    |key_len|ref              |rows|Extra
1 | SIMPLE     |names|index|PRIMARY,first  |PRIMARY|4      |NULL             |448 |Using where
1 | SIMPLE     |addr |ref  |last           |last   |4      |files.names.last |25  |Using where
```

EXPLAIN statement from remotehost:

```
id| select_type|table|type |possible_keys  |key    |key_len|ref              |rows|Extra
1 | SIMPLE     |names|range|PRIMARY,first  |first  |903    |NULL             |955 |Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 | SIMPLE     |addr |ref  |last           |last   |4      |files.names.last |25  |Using where
```

UPDATE:

```
Localhost is using mysql version 5.1.46-log. 
Remotehost is using mysql version 5.0.91-log.
```

Comment: Voting to move to ServerFault, as this is a system administration question, not a programming question.

Comment: please don't....this is a mysql question more than anything. There seems to be more mysql experts on this board

Comment: Compare my.cnf files to make sure something isn't badly misconfigured on remotehost. Sounds like you already checked, but make sure there is an index on addr.id on remotehost. Also, try running "optimize table names;" on remotehost to update statistics. You shouldn't have to do that, but I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have access to the my.cnf file on remotehost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post `mysqldump --no-data` output for both of these databases? Probably they're using different locales, ISAM types, different options, etc.?

Comment: Looks like I'm out of ideas. The only way I see is fairly brute force - load up build of MySQL with debugging info, hook up gdb and trace query plan decisions...

Answer (score 0):

Run SHOW CREATE TABLE on each table and look for differences. The first thing that came to mind was one of the servers has InnoDB enabled and the other doesn't, so the storage engines are different. Then check out my.cnf and SHOW VARIABLES for differences.

It also seems you have a different number of rows in the two databases. That can affect what indexes the planner decides to use in executing your query.

Comment: I have the exact same number of rows...I think the reason why it looks that way is because the two servers are using different indices...I will give your SHOW CREATE TABLE a go

Comment: I ran the show create table & they are the exact same...both are using the MyISAM db...everything else, including indices is also 100% the same...weird